# Paypal sandbox test payment for canada

Tags: php, paypal, woocommerce, paypal-sandbox

I am facing problem when test payment in sandbox account. When i select the country canada it`s give the error We do not ship to canada. I am not identifying what I am doing wrong in Woocommerce setting.

Website details ---

1 - it`s shopping Woocommerce Website And this is only for canada and United States (US) .

2 - When i select country Canada It`s give me error WE DO NOT SHIP TO CANADA.

Website URL - http://cnrugs.enbake.com/

Please help me

[Attached Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OW2qG.png)

Answer (score 0):

I have gone through your website and found that it is not the issue of payment gateways,  you haven't set the shipping for this region. You may go to Woocommerce ->settings->shipping tab and add shipping for canada region.

Comment: Hello Logon Young, I have added canada region North America, Canada and added all shipping methods for it`s give same error " We do not ship to canada " Can you tell me what is the setting process for canada in woocommerce. Thanks

Comment: The process would be to go to shipping tab, add a new shipping zone, enter the title of your zone, in select region field search for canada and select one of your suitable location and then add all shipping methods. These are quite easy steps and you can also watch woocommerce video how to add shipping zones.